# How can a version of a package conflict with itself?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, rpm

I want to install `fillup` and get:

```
 rpm -i fillup-1.42-268.1.x86_64.rpm 
    file /usr/bin/fillup conflicts between attempted installs of \
    fillup-1.42-268.1.x86_64 and fillup-1.42-268.1.x86_64
```

It looks like it's the same package that conflicts itself.

Why does this happen, and what can be done about it so that I can install `fillup`?

Comment: Are you sure you don't already have that package installed?

Comment: @Mat Yes I am sure!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This kind of error messages can appear if you try to install a package whose previous installation got aborted without completing.

`rpm` by default won't install a package if any of the file it needs to install already exists in the filesystem. So, if a previous installation aborted and some files were left behind, all succesive attempt will fail. The error message is quite confusing because `rpm` will try to find out which package the problematic file belongs to and in this case, it's the very same package it tries to install. The `--force` option tells `rpm` not to care and erase what it needs to perform the operation (that's why it may be risky, but if no other package claims the file, it's safe).

Comment: I ran into this with recently with `yum`. To resolve, I used `yumdownloader` to download the RPM, install it via `rpm -ivh --force package.rpm`, uninstalled it with `rpm -e package`, and then went about my originally-intended `yum install`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved this I mean at least the "what can be done about it" part I ran:

```
rpm -i --force fillup-1.42-268.1.x86_64.rpm
```

and it works now but still don't know why that error message happened.

Comment: Had you already tried to install it and aborted the installation? Looks like some files were left behind and `rpm` by default won't install a package if any of the file it needs to install already exists in the filesystem. The `--force` option tells `rpm` not to care and erase what it needs to perform the operation (that's why it may be risky).